# Is it possible to create nested helpers in dust.js?

Tags: javascript, gettext, dust.js

I am evaluating different template engines for i18n purposes and I wonder if it is possible to create nested helpers in dust.js in order to user both i18n and pluralization (or simply variables) for a single sentence.

Consider the following example from PHP/WordPress, which uses gettext along with printf:

```
<?php printf( _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', $comment_count ), $comment_count, $post_title ); ?>
```

Here we have `_n()` wrapped inside of `printf()`. Is this possible with dust.js helpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested helpers are definitely possible within `Dust.js`, as long as the nested helper is in the body of the outer helper (as opposed to being within the parameters). The `@select` helper is an example of nested helpers already in wide use.

```
{@select key=myKey}
  {@eq value="Yes"}YES{/eq}
  {@eq value="No"}NO{/eq}
  {@default}Neither here nor there{/default}
{/select}
```